# How to return the keyword causing a True flag in contains

Tags: python

The purpose of my Python script is to look for a few different strings in the html of a few websites, if it finds one of the strings it will return a True flag.

Code:

```
import operator
import requests
import threading

# search for any of these items
search_for = ['about me', 'home page', 'website', 'submit your link', 'add a link']

# threads
threads = []

def send_get_request(link, search_for):
    try:
        html = requests.get(link)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        return False, e
    text = html.text.lower()
    if any(operator.contains(text, keyword.lower()) for keyword in search_for):
        return (True, link)
    else:
        return (False, link)


def process_result(result):
    if True in result:
        with open("potentialLinks.txt", "a") as file:
            file.write('{}\n'.format(str(result)))
            print("Success: {}".format(str(result)))
    else:
        print("Failed: {}".format(str(result)))


def main():
    # open and loop the links
    with open("profiles.txt", "r") as links:
        for link in links:
            link = link.strip()
            results = send_get_request(link, search_for)
            process_result(results)


# entry point ...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What i'm having issues with is:

```
if any(operator.contains(text, keyword.lower()) for keyword in search_for):
```

When it finds a keyword in the html, is it possible for me to return which one of the keywords it has found to cause the True flag to trigger?

I cannot think of the best way to do this, more than likely i am over thinkinging something small, thank you for any help on the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import operator
search_for = ['cat', 'mouse']

text = "I want to kill my cat"
keywords = [kw for kw in search_for if operator.contains(text.lower(), kw.lower())]
print(keywords)

text = "I want to kill my cat because it ate my mouse"
keywords = [kw for kw in search_for if operator.contains(text.lower(), kw.lower())]
print(keywords)
```

Output:

```
['cat']
['cat', 'mouse']
```

You can check for a match by checking for the output list's length to be > 0

Answer (score 1):

```
found = None 
for keyword in ["apple" ,"cat"]:
     if keyword.lower() in "this is a cat and this is not":
          found = keyword
          break
```

And if you want all the matched keywords then use

```
[keyword for keyword in ["apple" ,"cat"] if keyword.lower() in "this is a cat and this is not an apple"]
```